# braintree + NodeJS gives an "authentication Error "

Tags: node.js, paypal, braintree

I'm trying to build a payment gateway library using *braintree's NodeJS* library, I'm making an *ajax* call from front end with the card data.

> Client-Side

```
var card_data = {
    type: "AmEx",
    number: "3XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    expire_month: "XX",
    expire_year: "201X",
    cvv2: "XXX",
    name: "sandeep",
    price : "200",
    currency : "USD"
};
```

Ajax call,

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/paymentPath_braintree",
    data: card_data
}).done(function(message){
    console.log(message);
}).fail(function(data, message){
    console.log(message);
});
```

> Server-Side

```
var braintreePay = require('braintree');
app.get("/payment_braintree", function(request, response){
    var data = request.query;
    var gateway = braintreePay.connect({
            environment: braintreePay.Environment.Sandbox,
            merchantId: "MymerchentID",
            publicKey: "MypublicKey",
            privateKey: "MyprivateKey",
    });
    var saleRequest = {
            amount: data.price,
            creditCard: {
                number: data.number,
                cvv: data.cvv2,
                expirationMonth: data.expire_month,
                expirationYear: data.expire_year.slice(2),
                cardHolder: data.name
            },
            options: {
                submitForSettlement: true
            }
    };
    gateway.transaction.sale(saleRequest, function(error, result){
            if(error){
                console.log(error.name);
                throw error;
            }
            if(result.success){
                response.send(result.transaction.id);
            } else {
                response.send(result.message);
            }
    });
});
```

I have cross checked everything, from keys and card data everything is in order but i am getting an error in callback after making *gateway.transaction.sale(...);* called **Authentication Error** . Which i tried to figure out for hours but could not get through.

error object is

```
authenticationError: Authentication Error
    arguments: undefined
    message: "Authentication Error"
    name: "authenticationError"
    stack: undefined
    type: "authenticationError"
```

### Where am i going wrong?

I have created an account [sandbox.braintreegateway](http://sandbox.braintreegateway.com) those key credentials are from the account that i have created, i din't create an app like how its done in paypal.
I am going through lack of understanding in Braintree integration.
Are their any proper documented resource.

Comment: Can you hardcode these to match your sandbox and see if the error persists?             environment: braintreePay.Environment.Sandbox,
            merchentId: "MymerchentID",
            publicKey: "MypublicKey",
            privateKey: "MyprivateKey",

Comment: Tried it but no luck.

Comment: I work at Braintree. First of all, that appears to be a real credit card number you've included in your question. I'm editing it out along with the expiration date and cvv, but you need to email Stack Overflow and ask them to remove it from the edit history (which is public).

Comment: Second, you need to tokenize or encrypt the credit card before passing it to your server. One of the main benefits of a service like Braintree is not having the same PCI compliance burden because you don't see raw credit card numbers. Our [getting started guides](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+node/start/overview) should show you how, and if you have any more questions I suggest you [email our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).

Comment: Those credentials are not real, i got them from here http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com, as i made use of them in sandbox with different credit cards, i wanted few. Later part i made use of the encryption library of JS it was very helpful.

Comment: @agf would it be ok to put the code on codeReview, as those are dummy data i have put them on github too, should i remove them. would their be an issue!

Comment: @SandeepkumarHR I recommend you email our support team. Our encryption library is no longer our recommended integration method. If you want dummy data, you should be using [test numbers from our docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/reference/general/testing#credit-card-numbers).

Comment: @agf thanks, i had mailed and i have got the proper guidance. Also in sandbox i can use only the specified numbers in the testing section,i've learned that other numbers would be invalid/not be accepted.